# Is the tap gesture for view working for all contents inside the view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to hidden some contents when touching anywhere in the View. I have a view and some labels and view as subview , If I add tap gesture for the main view, all the subview get respond? or I have to add tap gesture for each subview separately?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `touchesBegan:withEvents:` inside your main `UIView`. Every time you touch an element inside the `UIView` you can get the selected element from the touch and also set it hidden:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touch.view.hidden = YES;
}
```